# how to get pydoit to run all cmd-action tasks even if some have non-zero exit status?

Tags: python, doit

I would like to run all tasks even if some have non-zero exit status. I can do this with `doit --continue` from the command line, but would like to embed the directive in the `dodo.py` file itself. I've checked the docs but have been unable to find a way - my starting point is:

```
def task_lint():
    """Run checks on code."""
    return {
        "actions": [
            "pflake8",
            "isort --check .",
            "black --check ."
        ]
    }
```

In Make I would prefix commands with `-`:

```
check:
        -flake8
        -isort --check .
        -black --check .
```

What should I do in `doit`?

Answer (score 1):

```
DOIT_CONFIG = {
    "continue": True,
}


def task_lint():
    """Run checks on code."""
    yield {
        "name": "flake8",
        "actions": ["flake8"],
    }

    yield {
        "name": "isort",
        "actions": ["isort --check ."],
    }

    yield {
        "name": "black",
        "actions": ["black  --check ."],
    }
```

Notes:

1. `--continue` is for *tasks*, not *actions*.
   Your example is better written as 3 separate tasks.
   That also allows you to execute them individually (`doit lint:flake8`).
2. use `DOIT_CONFIG` to pass configuration (could also be done on INI or TOML files). Notice that `doit help run` command will display the *config name* to be used.

Comment: Thank you - if I only want `continue: True` for this task, and want other tasks to halt if any of their actions fail, how do I configure that? I've looked through the docs on pydoit.org but can't find that. (Is there a section in pydoit.org docs that documents all available configuration options?)

Comment: `--continue` can be applied only globally. Of course inside on your own task you can control what is considered a failure...

Comment: Full list of configuration options is only available per command through the CLI at the moment. I plan to add a section on docs, but that's low priority at the moment.